# Copy text in flutter along with text styling

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The textview in flutter has some styling(Font family,color,style etc) and when I try to copy the text, only the text value gets copied but I need styling also.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: The code simple. A variable stores demo string. The text widget is showing that string to the user. The text widget has some styling. When I copy that text by holding the text and paste it somewhere,  the pasted text doesn't has styling now. Only the demo string is pasted.

Comment: Have u found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 2):

styling properties are given to display text in given Style it is not the property of text.
Text is copied in UTF byte Format 
so, When you copy text Only text gets copied the style and Other property does not get copied.

Comment: Then what can be the solution? There are apps which allows you to copy and paste the text with different fonts.